# How to edit url before routing in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Actually my angularjs routing is working fine, but now I want to route to different route from the searched url.

ex.:
I have two urls that are:

/en/Feedback

/ar/Feedback

These two url should route to the same route below.

```
.when("/Feedback", {
    templateUrl: "/Scripts/Cms/Feedback.html",
    controller: "FeedBackCtrl"
})
```

And if possible, I want to get 'en' or 'ar' to a variable before `$routeProvider` route to the url.

note: `en` and `ar` cannot be passed as parameter. It should be in the same format as given in url.

Comment: Why don't you append it after /Feedback/:id and change the value of id dynamically by setting it to en or er

Comment: No. the url format can't change. How to route two url to the same route in angular js..??pls...anybody....this is eating my head...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i found a way to change the url. I will not prescribe that way...
i just modified the "angular-route.js".
I just Edit the url before route checking from our set of routes we defined, has happen from "route.js"